# What can I do about foggy double glazed windows?

Tags: windows

We have double glazing throughout our house, and most of the windows have started to "fog up".  Doing a quick search revealed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzTIzfrn1OM) video, which looks very much like the problem that we have.  I have two questions:

- How realistic is this video (there seems to be a plethora of similar services / claims out there)?
- Is this type of service available in the UK, and is it likely to be financially viable (i.e. could it work out more expensive that replacing the windows)?

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but our windows have a UPVC frame.

Comment: Do you mean that moisture is getting between the panes of glass?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.  That would certainly be my guess, but the symptom is that the glass is foggy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is a sign that the seals have failed and moisture is getting inside the window.  The video you posted seems to be of a service that can apply a solution to prevent the fogging, however the seals are still gone which means the window is no longer insulating as it should be.

Depending how new they are, they might still be under warranty in which case you should contact the manufacturer.  Otherwise you can contact a glazer to see what would be involved in replacing the glass and seals, though sometimes it's cheaper just to replace the whole window.

Comment: We ended up replacing just the glass.

Comment: It is very rare in the UK for replacing the whole window (i.e. frame) to be cheaper than replacing the double-glazed units (i.e. buying new bits of glass that have been connected with seals).